# Assist me get the program to read index numbers from a text file?

Tags: c++

```
void login() {
string name;
string username;
string password;
string usernameFromFile;
string passwordFromFile;

ifstream infile;
infile.open(name + ".txt");
cout << "Please enter your username \n";
cin >> username;
}
```

I am trying to get this program to compare an entered password to one that has been saved in a text file, that would be in the index number of 1 in the text file, can someone help me?

Comment: Please add an example of your text file. Does it contain nothing but the password?

Comment: How are you trying to read the password from the user? How are you trying to read it from the text file? How are you trying to compare them?

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ read file vector".  Also try "c++ read file csv".

Comment: The text file is written to in a separate part of the program and it ends up like this          username, password      each being filled in respectively

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
ifstream infile {name + “.txt”};
string password;
infile >> password;
```

Comment: The `getline` function may be better suited than `infile >>` because `getline` allows for whitespace in the password.